# Without using separate link, I want to make item name in a list as a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

```
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.courseCategory)
          @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "newButton_view" })
```

The above code segment is in my view. All course names are displaying and when Details link clicks it will shows the course details of selected course. What I want is to use course name as a link in-spite of using  another keyword as a link.

Comment: Replace the first `"Details"` with `item.courseName`

Comment: Thank you so much  @StephenMuecke it is working now. :)